# Need Ruby method to convert an array of strings into a Hash

Tags: ruby

I need Ruby method to convert an array of strings into a Hash where each key is a string and each value is the 1-indexed index of the string in the original array.

```
hashify(%w(a b c)) 
# should return 
{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3}
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I feel like you're missing a valuable opportunity to learn the ruby language.

Comment: Is this functionality you're likely to reuse in many places? I might also consider naming the method something more descriptive to what it does like, `to_hash_one_indexed` because this seems like very specific functionality.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. We expect to see your effort.

Comment: @ the Tin Man: I have visited all the links provided by you and will take care of asking question with proper format and mentioning what i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def hashify(array)
  array.each.with_index(1).to_h
end

hashify(%w(a b c))
#=> { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 }
```

Comment: (Trivial, but OP stated they wanted it 1-indexed.)

Answer (score 2):

Even though I think I'm helping someone do their homework, I can't resist taking a golf swing, because Ruby is awesome:

```
%w(a b c).each.with_index(1).to_h
```

Also, defining "hashify" is VERY un-Ruby-like. I'd suggest alternatives, but it's probably a homework assignment anyways and you don't seem to want to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

There are (clearly) multiple ways you could achieve your goal in Ruby.

If you consider the expression `%w(a b c).map.with_index(1).to_h`, you can see that it is a matter of stringing together a few methods provided to us by the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) class.

By first sending the [:map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) message to the array, we receive back an [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html), which provides us the handy [:with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) method.  As you can see in the docs, with_index accepts an offset in an argument, so offsetting your indices by 1 is as simple as passing 1 as your argument to `:with_index`.

Finally, we call `:to_h` on the enumerator to receive the desired hash.

```
# fore!
def hashify(array) 
  array.map.with_index(1).to_h
end
> hashify %w(a b c)
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: (Trivial, but OP stated they wanted it 1-indexed.)

Comment: misread the question, but thank you for the scrutiny.  I was aware of the arg but just overlooked the detail.  Cheers.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will add a method `to_hash_one_indexed` to the `Array` class.

```
class Array
  def to_hash_one_indexed
    map.with_index(1).to_h
  end
end
```

Then to call it:

```
%w(a b c).to_hash_one_indexed
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) is already defined. It is probably a bad idea to override a Ruby core method...

Comment: (Trivial, but OP stated they wanted it 1-indexed.)